# Paginator aligning vertically

Tags: datatable, paginator

We code in Vue 3 and Nuxt with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS.

I have created a DataTable (Primevue) with paginator embedded in it. Somehow, the paginator is aligned vertically instead of horizontally. We must make it horizontal. I have tried a lot to make it horizontal but with no good result. Could you please help me? Here is the screenshot shown in vertical alignment.

[image: misaligned paginator]

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otfWK.png)

I have tried many different CSS options like scroll-x/scroll-y both true/false, frozen-columns="1/2/3/4/5 etc", class="display nowrap p-3 text-left and etc", size="sm", and etc.
I also have tried standlone <Paginator tag, too, but the result was worse.
CSS like below also has been tried in vain.
.p-datatable .p-paginator {
...
text-align: left;
display: inline; // flex, inline-flex, etc
}

Comment: Why you should not upload [images of code, data, errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365) when asking a question. Instead, provide the code as formatted text. Ideally, provide that code as part of a [mre].

Comment: You may also want to add some more specific tags to your question, to attract the relevant domain experts. Right now, you may not get many people looking at your question. Both the `datatable` and `paginator` tags are fairly generic. You probably shouldn't even be using the `datatable` tag - hover your mouse over it to see why.